# MAX() OVER () with order by 2 columns function producing inconsistent results Hive

Tags: hive

Team,

I have MAX() OVER () with order by 2 columns function used in the hiveQL code but it producing me inconsistent results. Any thought why it is behaving like this?

This is something I am trying to covert Teradata code to Hive code and in Teradata we have MAX() OVER () with order by 2 columns function and again we have using the function with "qualify" the column in the below section with condition as IS NULL, I can recreate the function in Hive and I used Having clause to satisfy the need but I suspect MAX() OVER () with order by 2 columns function is the culprit which is not passing me right value for Having clause. Any thought?? sometime it gives me right result but sometime its not.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use `Having clause` to restrict the records . Remember `MAX is aggregate function` and `MAX() OVER () is analytical function` . Equivalent for **QUALIFY** is `ROW_NUMBER()` and to restrict the records use `ROW_NUMBER()` along with `Sub Query.`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Could you please share some example, below is what currently I written... select max(col1) over partition by (col2,col3) Order by(col1,col4) DESC ROWS between 1 preceding and 1 preceding as col5 group by col2,col3 having col5 is null

Comment: Any update on the example or anyone share some sample for above. thanks